# how to position a div on top section of its parent div

Tags: html, css

Somewhere in a page, how to make div-a2 position above div-a1? Of course, I cannot make div-a2 above div-a1 in the layout below.

```
<div id=a>

<div id=a1> something here
</div>
<div id=a2> show this part first
</div>

</div>
```

still looking for better solution. thanks

Comment: by "above" do you mean positioned or layered?

Comment: i have no idea. if css alone cannot do it

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand the question, I thought layered.

Comment: @sp00m You wouldn't need jQuery for either position or layered. Try not to muddy the water by adding behaviour (with JS) when the solution can be done purely presentationally (with CSS).

Comment: That's why I didn't answered dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with pure css. Write like this:

```
#a{
    display:-moz-box;
    display:box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -moz-box-direction:reverse;
    box-direction: reverse;
    -moz-box-direction:reverse;
    -webkit-box-direction:reverse;  
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    box-orient:vertical;     
}
```

'
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ASVtx/1/

Comment: i actually did a test, only chrome works, not working in IE or firefox

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss read my comment i already said it's a css3 property. Which means it's not work in IE8 & below

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give the elements absolute position css, and then position them appropriately depending on the content size of each like:

```
#a1,#a2{position:absolute;}
#a2{  top: 0; }
#a1{  top: 200px;}
```

OR, within the parent:

```
#a1,#a2{position:relative;}
#a2{  top: 0; }
#a1{  top: 200px;}
```

Or, a perhaps better alternate is to change the layout order (but I assume that is not possible for some reason not stated).

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/CRCvU/

See this updated example where I used em instead of px for the position, gave the parent a border so you see its scope, and added stuff around the parent. http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/CRCvU/1/

Just in case you want to go that way, here is the jQuery code to do this:

```
var ah1 = $('#a1').height();
var ah2 = $('#a2').height();
var ah = $('#a').height();
var relpos = {float:"left",
    display: "inline-block",
    position: "relative",
    clear: "both"
};
$('#a').css({
    height: ah
});
$('#a1, #a2').css(relpos);
$('#a2').css('top', -ah1);
$('#a1').css('top', ah2);
```

Working scripted example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/CRCvU/3/

Comment: it's not 0, the parent div is just somewhere in a page, not the whole page

Comment: SO the relative is likely what you desire then.

Comment: hi, mark, what if i don't know the height of div-a2? i really don't know the height of div-a2. thx

Comment: seems like we need to know both heights here. i hope i can get a better solution.